# Redux - passing state to other components

Tags: redux

I'm pretty new to Redux and i've read that one of its major benefits is that every component in your app can access the store's state and you don't need to pass it around from one component to another.

So i created a component called `Main` and "connected" it to the state and dispatch mapping functions:

`withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main))`

And inside of `Main` i have some code in the `render()` function like:

```
  )}/>
    <Route path="/login" render={() => (
      <Login {...this.props} />

  )}/>
```

So in this example, i can access the store's state inside of my `Login` component since i passed it to it as of its props (using `Main`'s props).

If i remove the `{...this.props}` part, i can no longer access the store state from that `Login` component - so how is it any different? It looks like whenever i want to access the store state i have to pass it around.

Another unrelated question that i have:
Is it ok to use component state in some components in addition to the store state?

Comment: Did you also connect the Login component to the state? If you did this then it should work.

I've used both Redux state and component state in one app. I don't think you should handle for example an input state with Redux.

Comment: No i haven't. Do i need to connect every component with the state if i want it to access it? Let's say i have 10 such components, do i have to import the store and use `Provider` and `connect` for each one of them?

Comment: That's how I've always understood Redux. If there is not state then it's a pure component, if it's got logic - it's a container. Try adding the connect function with proper parameters (`mapStateToProps` & `mapDispatchToProps`) and it should be okay. But you should only use one `Provider` on the main component of your application. Take a look here: https://redux.js.org/basics/exampletodolist

Comment: Yeah as soon as i defined the `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` and connected them to my `Login` component it worked. 
Is this the only way of doing it then?

Also - if i use `Provider` to provide the store (and hence its `state` and `dispatch`) to a component - all of its children components would have access to `state` and `dispatch` as well with no "extra work" - right?